# Why is this getting converted to a cross join in spark?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

We have `posts` dataframe. I derive `questions` and `answers` dataframes from `posts` as below

```
val questions = spark.sql("select * from posts where posts._PostType = 'Question'")
val answers = spark.sql("select * from posts where posts._PostType = 'Answer'")
```

I need to find all the answers of each post (`_ParentId` col of `answers` points to the `_Id` col of `questions`). So I wrote the following

```
spark.sql("select q._id, q._PostType, q._ParentId, a._id, a._PostType, a._ParentId from questions q, answers a join questions on q._id = a._parentId")
```

**Questions**

1. Why is this resulting in a cross join?
2. How can i group all the answers of a given question?

**Output**

```
scala> spark.sql("select _id, _postType, _parentId from posts").show
+---+---------+---------+
|_id|_postType|_parentId|
+---+---------+---------+
|  4| Question|        0|
|  6| Question|        0|
|  7|   Answer|        4|
|  9| Question|        0|
| 11| Question|        0|
| 12|   Answer|       11|
| 13| Question|        0|
| 14| Question|        0|
| 16| Question|        0|
| 17| Question|        0|
| 18|   Answer|       17|
+---+---------+---------+

scala> spark.sql("select _id,_PostType, _ParentId from  questions").show
+---+---------+---------+
|_id|_PostType|_ParentId|
+---+---------+---------+
|  4| Question|        0|
|  6| Question|        0|
|  9| Question|        0|
| 11| Question|        0|
| 13| Question|        0|
| 14| Question|        0|
| 16| Question|        0|
| 17| Question|        0|
+---+---------+---------+


scala> spark.sql("select _id,_PostType, _ParentId from  answers").show
+---+---------+---------+
|_id|_PostType|_ParentId|
+---+---------+---------+
|  7|   Answer|        4|
| 12|   Answer|       11|
| 18|   Answer|       17|
+---+---------+---------+

scala> spark.sql("select q._id, q._PostType, q._ParentId, a._id, a._PostType, a._ParentId from questions q, answers a cross join questions on q._id = a._parentId").show(100,false)
+---+---------+---------+---+---------+---------+
|_id|_PostType|_ParentId|_id|_PostType|_ParentId|
+---+---------+---------+---+---------+---------+
|4  |Question |0        |7  |Answer   |4        |
|4  |Question |0        |7  |Answer   |4        |
|4  |Question |0        |7  |Answer   |4        |
|4  |Question |0        |7  |Answer   |4        |
|4  |Question |0        |7  |Answer   |4        |
|4  |Question |0        |7  |Answer   |4        |
|4  |Question |0        |7  |Answer   |4        |
|4  |Question |0        |7  |Answer   |4        |
|11 |Question |0        |12 |Answer   |11       |
|11 |Question |0        |12 |Answer   |11       |
|11 |Question |0        |12 |Answer   |11       |
|11 |Question |0        |12 |Answer   |11       |
|11 |Question |0        |12 |Answer   |11       |
|11 |Question |0        |12 |Answer   |11       |
|11 |Question |0        |12 |Answer   |11       |
|11 |Question |0        |12 |Answer   |11       |
|17 |Question |0        |18 |Answer   |17       |
|17 |Question |0        |18 |Answer   |17       |
|17 |Question |0        |18 |Answer   |17       |
|17 |Question |0        |18 |Answer   |17       |
|17 |Question |0        |18 |Answer   |17       |
|17 |Question |0        |18 |Answer   |17       |
|17 |Question |0        |18 |Answer   |17       |
|17 |Question |0        |18 |Answer   |17       |
+---+---------+---------+---+---------+---------+
```

Comment: looking at your code with the print statement. .it has cross join instead of join  or left join.  however your snippet earlier has the correct join clause.  can you look at you code and confirm that it is using join.  also I like the scala way of joining DF's makes it much easier  just for your information

Comment: @Aaron I tried with the following and i get the same error: val qanda = questions.join(answers, questions("_Id") === answers("_ParentId"), "inner")